# Multiple integral of min

Tags: definite-integrals

How can this be proven?
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1...\int_0^1 min(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) dx_1dx_2...dx_n = \frac1{n+1} $$

I tried to split the last integral in $$\int_0^{min(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1})} x_ndx_n + \int_{min(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1})}^1 min(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1})dx_n$$

And then continue in this manner. 
So the function that remains to be integrated satisfies this recurrence relation
$$ f_n = (1-x)f_{n-1} + \int f_{n-1}  $$

I then thought to use the following notation

$$I_n = \frac{ (-1)^{n+1}x^n }{n} +  \frac{ (-1)^{n}x^{n-1} }{n-1} $$

If we compute the last integral, the n-1 integrals apply to $I_2$
If we apply another integral we get $I_3+I_2$ and so on, which will look like Pascal's triangle. But I can't go any further.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another opproach:

First consider the set $A=\{(t_1,\dots,t_n):t_1\le\dots\le t_n\}$. In this set, your integral becomes
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^{t_n}...\int_0^{t_2} \int_0^{t_1} x_1 dx_1dx_2...dx_n = \frac1{(n+1)!}.
$$

Since there are $n!$ sets like $A$ which are the union is $[0,1]^n$ then 
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1...\int_0^1 min(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) dx_1dx_2...dx_n = n!\times  \frac1{(n+1)!}=\frac1{n+1}.
$$

Comment: Very nice! (+1)

Comment: Thank you! Very nice indeed.

Comment: You're wellcome ;)

Comment: This elegant solution deserves +1 upvote!

Answer (score 3):

First, write

\begin{align*}
I
&:= \int_{0}^{1} \cdots \int_{0}^{1} \min \{ x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n} \} \, dx_{n}\cdots dx_{1} \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \cdots \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\min \{ x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n} \}} dt \, dx_{n}\cdots dx_{1}.
\end{align*}

By noting that $t \leq \min \{x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n}\}$ is equivalent to $t \leq x_{1}, \cdots, t \leq x_{n}$, we find that $I$ is the volume of the region $\mathcal{W}$ defined by

$$ \mathcal{W} = \{ (t, x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n}) : 0 \leq t \leq 1, t \leq x_{1} \leq 1, \cdots, t \leq x_{n} \leq 1 \}. $$

Thus by Fubini's Theorem we have

\begin{align*}
I
&= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{t}^{1} \cdots \int_{t}^{1} \, dx_{n}\cdots dx_{1} \, dt
 = \int_{0}^{1} (1-t)^{n} \, dt
 = \frac{1}{n+1}.
\end{align*}

This solution can be encoded in the language of probability as follows: Let $U_{1}, \cdots, U_{n}$ be i.i.d. uniform random variables on $[0, 1]$. Then

\begin{align*}
&\int_{0}^{1} \cdots \int_{0}^{1} \min \{ x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n} \} \, dx_{n}\cdots dx_{1} \\
&\qquad = \Bbb{E}( \min\{ U_{1}, \cdots, U_{n} \} ) \\
&\qquad = \int_{0}^{1} \Bbb{P}(\min\{ U_{1}, \cdots, U_{n} \} > x) \, dx \\
&\qquad = \int_{0}^{1} \Bbb{P}( U_{1} > x, \cdots, U_{n} > x) \, dx \\
&\qquad = \int_{0}^{1} \Bbb{P}( U_{1} > x)^{n} \, dx \qquad (\because \text{i.i.d.}) \\
&\qquad = \int_{0}^{1} (1 - x)^{n} \, dx
= \frac{1}{n+1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding where this equality comes from, since I haven't studied continuous random variables $$E(min(...)) = \int_0^1 P(min(...)>x) dx$$. Thank you!

Comment: @user42768, Actually, that follows from Fubini's Theorem but I admit that it is not an easy observation. My calculus-version solution has the same content as in that solution, so you may ignore that part.

Comment: So the proof to that equality is based on the "calculus" method of solving the problem? Thank you for your time.

Comment: How did you apply Fubini's theorem? can someone enlight me on this? thx

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that, $\min \{a,b\} = (a+b-|a-b|)/2$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure, apologies if the conversation stops suddenly. I will pick it up later. I think to see this, first just work on the case $n=2$. Then use the above expression to evaluate it. I will try this out myself now and post soon.

Comment: I already solved for n=2 using the method I described. Using an absolute value requires splitting of the integral, so it is similar to the way I thought to solve it.

Comment: Using the absolute value you can use symmetry along the line x=y to remove it :-) that is how far I was getting. I have to stop at the minute, I will try to resume soon, but it seems you now have a solution below!